# CrmServiceClient extremely slow when connected to Microsoft Dynamics online / 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

I'm trying to use CrmServiceClient class from the last CRM SDK to retrieve data from a Dynamics 365 environment.

CrmServiceClient caches connection info, **even when new instances of CrmServiceClient are created and disposed!**. My application connects to different CRMs urls, so I use the flag "RequireNewInstance=true;" in the connection string to avoid caching.

When this flag is used, the performance is terrible (more than 30 seconds to retrieve any data).

Any clues how can I get acceptable performance when accessing different online CRMs?

Here is a simple sample code, but any service call takes a lot of time, not just this:

```
string connectionString="Url=https://myTest.api.crm.dynamics.com/; Username=myUser@myTest.onmicrosoft.com; Password=myPassword; AuthType=Office365;RequireNewInstance=true;";

using (var client = new Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient(connectionString))
    {
        var orgService = (IOrganizationService)client.OrganizationWebProxyClient ?? client.OrganizationServiceProxy;
        var response = (RetrieveVersionResponse)orgService.Execute(new RetrieveVersionRequest());
    }
```

Note: I used to use the CrmConnection class from previous SDKs, this had much better response times but now this cannot be used to access CRM online (v 8.1.1 or above)

Comment: Why don't you new up a new CrmServiceClient for each instance? instead of trying to bypass the cache?

Comment: As I commented in the post, CrmServiceClient caches connection info even if you create new instances. I don't know why they choose to implement it that way, but is the way it works.

Comment: I just tried by connecting to 2 different environments by newing up the client and it worked as expected for me. I did not include `RequireNewInstance` config attribute either.

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM Marcos is correct. The latest versions of the SDK always cache, you can see an example here: http://crmtipoftheday.com/2016/12/15/crmserviceclient-and-multiple-instances/

Comment: @MattDearing very interesting, the only difference is I tried connecting to 2 different on-prem orgs and used 2016 SDK. Queried for a contact record which exists in one environment and not the other and the results were as expected.

Comment: @dynamicallyCRM I believe the change occured in SDK 8.2.0.1  "RequireNewInstance=True will now properly create a unique connection instance, RequireNewInstance = false, will now properly reuse the cached instance of the connection,  default is ‘false’" https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly/